# How to make a list of a class which has a list in it?

Tags: c#

I have a class Person for adding some data to a person. From a second class ListOfP I am able to display the data after each added new person. Now I need some help to put each new person into a list and be able to display every person within the list with all their details. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Person
{
    public List<string> PhoneNbrList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> GetListOfListOfP() { return PhoneNbrList; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void AddNewPerson()
    {
        PhoneNbrList = new List<string>();
        int i = 1;
        string str = "";
        bool stop = false;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("PhoneNbr [" + i + "]: ");
            str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str == "n")
                stop = true;
            else
                PhoneNbrList.Add(str);
            i++;
        } while (!stop);
        Console.Write("First name: ");
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Last name: ");
        LastName = Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public void ShowPersonData() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PhoneNbrList.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("PhoneNbr[" + (i + 1) + "]: " + PhoneNbrList[i]);

        Console.WriteLine("First name: " + FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("Last name: " + LastName);
    }
}


This is the second class

class ListOfP
    {
        static List<Person> ListP = new List<Person>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person lp = new Person();
            int counter = 1;

            lp.AddNewPerson();
            lp.ShowPersonData();
            ListP.Add(lp);


            lp.AddNewPerson();
            lp.ShowPersonData();
            ListP.Add(lp);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: _"Now I need some help"_ You have already started, where you've got stuck? Did you get an exception or what happened?

Comment: Any problem with `List<Person>`?

Comment: " From a second class ListOfP I am able to display the data after each added new person". where is that second class? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your person class;

```
class Person
{
    public List<string> PhoneNbrList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> GetListOfListOfP() { return PhoneNbrList; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

then use generics for where you need your list of person;

```
List<Person> myList = new List<Person>;
Person x = new Person();
myList.Add(x);
```

you can then loop through this list - or do whatever you want with it

```
foreach (Person p in myList)
{
//Do something
}
```

Comment: I did try the foreach like that and working fine for fisrt and last name but don't know how do the same with the list of phonenbr. That is a list so a bit different and  I am not that pro yet :)

Comment: to loop through the list of phonenumbers you need to say foreach (string s in PhoneNbrList) { //Do something } - in the loop you can reference each phone number with s as in Console.Writeline(s);

Comment: That is it. Ty, I didn't realized for a list in a list I needed a loop in a loop.

Comment: its not a list in a list - its a list in a class;

so every person can have multiple phone numbers - your other list contains all your person instances - so you have a list of person class insances, each instance has a list of numbers.

Comment: True. What I mean I must loop both. I hope I wrote right this time :)

Comment: So can you accept this as the answer?

Comment: Yes, now I able to continue on that path. Ty for all the fast answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have understood, you need something like this:

**UPDATE:**

```
class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
      PhoneNbrList = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string> PhoneNbrList;
    public List<string> GetListOfListOfP() { return PhoneNbrList; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

List<Person> objPerson = new List<Person>();

Person obj1 = new Person();
//Initialise obj1 here
objPerson.Add(obj1);

Person obj2 = new Person();
//Initialise obj2 here
objPerson.Add(obj2);

......// Add all the objects to list in same manner


// Query through list

foreach(var item in objPerson)
{
   // Access each of the items of list here
   foreach(var phoneNumbers in item.PhoneNbrList)
   {
      **//Access your each phone number here**
   }
}
```

Comment: I did try the foreach like that and working fine for fisrt and last name but don't know how do the same with the list of phonenbr. That is a list so a bit different and I am not that pro yet :)

Comment: @Godriel: I have updated the answer, and tested it myself. Works fine; please try it. Accept the answer if it works. Reply in case of other issue.